# node.js What does Date#getTime() do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gettime

I'm working on learnyounode module 13 right now. In the hints section it claims "Date#getTime() will also come in handy."

I looked up the Date object and found the getTime method, but what does it mean when there's a hash instead of a period?

Comment: It's just referring to the method on the Date constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a refference to `getTime` method of `Date` object. It is normal syntax when you talk about documentations.

According to [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.9) it returns [this time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5) (the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.).

Comment: It's basically the same as a Unix Timestap but with millisecond precision. You can get the current Unix Timestap with `new Date().getTime() / 1000`

Comment: There is nothing about Unix in question? What is the goal of your comment?

Comment: I think @dusky meant that dividing the return value of `getTime` by 1000 is the equivalent of a UNIX timestamp (or Epoch time)

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question, but the learnyounode problem asks you to get the Epoch time.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Date.now()` is quite a lot faster than `+new Date()` or `new Date().getTime()`.  If you care about speed or memory collection jitter you should avoid `new Date()`.  For a benchmark see:  http://jsperf.com/date-now-vs-new-date-gettime/14 Note: the versions with lower-case date assume that the date doesn't change which isn't applicable in most circumstances.  The same applies with nodejs.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

getTime function return unix timestamp

```
let nd = new Date();
let currentTime = nd.getTime();
console.log(currentTime);
```