# JavaScript loop between date range and return right format

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, ecmascript-6

How should I iterate between time range and set each day a new data in format YYYY-mm-dd for some filed in the object?

```
const index =  (time) =>  {
return {index: `time-&{time}`} // YYYY-mm-dd
}

const start = new Date(2018, 03, 28);
const end = new Date(2019, 03, 28);


let loop = new Date(start); // should be let loop here I guess
while(loop <= end){         

   var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
   loop = new Date(newDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
   index(loop)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some corrections were needed.

Use `${}` instead of `&{}` in `string` for variables.

Dates can be compared with `date.getTime()` which is a

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

Just check beginning and end condition.

```js
const index = (time) => {
  return {
    index: `time-${time}`
  } // YYYY-mm-dd
}

const start = new Date(2018, 03, 28);
const endTime = new Date(2018, 04, 28).getTime();


let loop = new Date(start);
while (loop.getTime() <= endTime) {
  let nextDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
  loop = new Date(nextDate);
  console.log(index(loop.toISOString().substring(0, 10)))
}
```

Comment: I'm working in node , actually getTime() is not a function in node, any idea?

Comment: are you sure?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482015/node-js-what-does-dategettime-do?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa